# How to post xcode textfield value to json

Tags: iphone, json

I am creating one php file and upload into mywebsite.Now how to insert value from xcode textfield to json.please any one know help me

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to post this data from Xcode... Don't you want to do it from your iOS app instead?

Comment: Your question is wrong.... xcode textfield??

Comment: I'm new to ios how to post value from xcode

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict1=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:textfield.text,@"filename",nil];
NSString *jsonString1=[jsonDict1 JSONRepresentation];
NSString *post1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"json=%@",jsonString1];
```

Comment: I have an json format like this { "Bookname": [ { "book0": "Master Key to Riches by Napoleon Hill"}]} and how  to post "book1" value through xcode

Answer (score 0):

```
const char *bytes = "mydata=Hello%20World";

NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<mydata>%@</mydata>", data];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```